# Python/Django auto typecasting datetime field to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, django

I am using

```
query = mysql_query
mysql = connection.cursor()
mysql.execute(mysql)
```

to get my result by providing raw sql query. It is working fine but while fetching datetime time field it is giving `datetime.datetime(2011,8,3,0,0)` but if execute same query in mysql it is not typecasting. Please where anything is missing

Comment: You can use raw SQL with Django, too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: You almost never need cursor.execute(sql). What do you want to do? Maybe MyModel.objects.filter(...).values_list(...) does help you?

Answer (score 1):

The database stores date/time values as a string internally. When you retrieve it through Django, then Django casts this into a `datetime.datetime` object for your convenience. If you retrieve the value directly from the database yourself, you will get the raw string and will therefore need to do any casting yourself.